# Label no se pinta en Node

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphviz, pydot

tengo el inconveniente que no escribe los labels en los nodos si no el nombre del nodo 
según tengo entendido

```
            node = pydot.Node("AB", label = "b")
```

me= debería de escribir b en el nodo  pero me escribe AB un ejemplo en la imagen el label de los edge es el mismo que el de los nodos pero en los nodos escribe el nombre

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el con el que genero

```
def AddNode(padre,nombre,graph:pydot.Dot,NT,cadena,producciones):
subp = FindSub(nombre,cadena[0],producciones)
for i in subp:

    if i !="":
        node = pydot.Node(nombre+i, label    = i)
        edge = pydot.Edge(padre,node,label = i)
        graph.add_edge(edge)
        if i in NT:
            cadena1 = copy.deepcopy(cadena)
            cadena1 = cadena[1:]
            AddNode(node,i,graph,NT,cadena1,producciones)
```

la creacion del grafico como tal si me lo genera pero no el label 
por poner un ejemplo si i = "a" y el nodo es hijo de A el nombre del nodo es Aa  y su label a pero escribe Aa en el nodo

Comment: Hola Angel ¿Podrías agregar el código de como generas el gráfico al completo para proveer un [mcve]? Lo digo porque yo al menos mediante add_node/add_edge no soy capaz de reproducir el problema.

Comment: ya lo he agregado

Answer (score 1):

Añade el nodo al grafo antes de añadir el vértice:

```
node = pydot.Node(nombre+i, label    = i)
graph.add_node(node)
edge = pydot.Edge(padre,node,label = i)
graph.add_edge(edge)
```

---

```
import pydot

graph = pydot.Dot(graph_type='graph')
graph.add_node(pydot.Node('A'))

nombre = "A"
i = "b"

node = pydot.Node(nombre+i, label=i)
edge = pydot.Edge(nombre, nombre+i, label=i)
graph.add_edge(edge)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import pydot

graph = pydot.Dot(graph_type='graph')
graph.add_node(pydot.Node('A'))

nombre = "A"
i = "b"

node = pydot.Node(nombre+i, label=i)
graph.add_node(node)
edge = pydot.Edge(nombre, nombre+i, label=i)
graph.add_edge(edge)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias por la solución